# trying angular MutationObserver so I can limit the height of a div

Tags: html, angular, mutation-observers

How can I catch changes to a div?  A div with contenteditable set on it, and has [hidden] elements that become visible at times. This single page app layout shouldn't scroll but stay in the viewable window area.

I'm using angular-split to have adjustable partitions in one of the components. Everything works and looks as it should, until content is added or changed to one of the Splits that makes the div height expand. When it expands beyond the bottom edge of the window the surrounding Splits break.  The overall window is not a set height and can be resized.  Using CSS with 'overflow: auto' the div still expands.

I'm trying to catch all changes to that div so I can manually calculate the correct height and set it.

html:

```
<div id="detail_container" [ngClass]="infoDisplay" #watchThis>
```

component.ts:

```
@ViewChild("watchThis") watchthis: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log(mutation.type);
      //height adjustments
    }); 
  });
  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
  this.observer.observe(this.watchthis.nativeElement, config);
}
```

No errors, but no console.logs either.

Comment: Can you share a plunkr?

Comment: MutationObserver observes changes in DOM. You probably need ResizeObserver or IntersectionObserver. Also, hopefully you know that without `subtree: true` you observe only immediate child nodes of this.watchthis.nativeElement.

Comment: @raviteja.kvns Maybe you have issue with other logics in your code. Could you please put a minimal working code demonstrating your issue in https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the scope. Try to call the console.log() out of a component method.

```
@ViewChild("watchThis") watchthis: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {

    this.log('mutations: ', mutations);

    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

      this.log('mutation.type: ', mutation.type);

      //height adjustments
    }); 
  });
  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
  this.observer.observe(this.watchthis.nativeElement, config);
}

log(caller: string, object: any) {
    console.log(caller, object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark I believe that you have a fundamental misunderstanding Angular vs whats available in modern native browser Javascript. ‘MutationObserver’ is a newer supported JavaScript API standard where you may listen to DOM mutations which occur and then gives you opportunity to query the DOM tree in and may more modern, thoughtful, optimized and performant way. It is literally an alternative approach to ‘.setEventListener’ and follows the reactive nature we are seeing in a percentage of applications who have to resort to Vue, Angular or AngularJS, React, Handlebars, (etc, etc the list goes on and on and the on as you already know) and product teams are adopting data driven UI frameworks, architectural patterns in order to manage complex user, efficient, interfaces that are being developed in todays day in age.

Now, to give context, consider my current use case for ‘MutationObserver’. I have started building my my very own super-lightweight asynchronous MVC UI using jQLite/sizzle as a DOM helper library with my own change detection built into it. React uses and VueJS use internal DOM diff algorithm against their proprietary in memory virtual DOM with a find and patch technique to set/reset/update the view, based on changes from the view model which are missing from the virtual tree and rendering just what has changed. AngularJS uses a less performant technique by default which is to poll the ‘$.scope.vm...’ view model using an polling interval which deep compares the current model to the most recently “cached” version in memory. If a change is detected it then updates the DOM where the changed model has been referenced and then re-initialized the component lifecycle against the ‘dirty’ model which updates the client view accordingly. As far as I know, none use the more performant and standardized MutationObserver which is why I am writing this light framework.